# Incorporating prop validation

Tags: javascript, html, validation, vue.js

How do I make so that my code return warning in the console if the Prop-value is not string?
The `player-name`-prop is supposed to be equal to string at all times.

If this: `<greet :player-name="5"></greet>` contains a number, I want to return a warning from my code below:

```
Vue.component('greet', {
  props: {
    'player-name': {
      type: String,
      required: true

    }

  },
  data() {
    return {

    }
  },
  props: ['player-name'],
  template: '<div>Welcome, {{playerName}}!</div>'
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue itself warns you that prop validation failed. Check the devtools console out.

You should get a warning like this:

[image: You Should get a warning like this]

Comment: As I discovered that you are declaring props twice in your component, your last declaration (just array `props`) overrides the first declaration, where you have type checking. remove this line `props: ['player-name']` and it will work correctly